# Visual Studio Code error while running Python code by Code Runner on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I changed my operating system on Ubuntu 2 weeks ago. I installed Visual Studio Code and an extension Code Runner. When i wanted to run a code i got a following information:

```
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
```

I searched the internet and i found that i have to print at the beginning of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

My question is can i change it somewhere in VSCode settings or somewhere else so as not to print this sequence whenever i want to make a new project. Also when I had this extension on Windows i didn't have such a problem. Moreover when i run code in C++ or in other languages i don't have this problem, i have it only in Python. Also i don't have this problem without Code Runner extension. I have it only with Code Runner extension and when i want to run Python code. Picture to visualize a problem.

[Code Runner Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0jWB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the problem here is that, in most of GNU/Linux os, the command for python if you're running python3 is `python3` instead of as in windows simply `python`, the simple `python` command only works for python2 in linux. So you can do 2 things first, go to `~/.bashrc`, open it in any text editor, at the end add this

```sh
alias python="python3"
```

or if you don't want to add an alias, you can make `python` to `python3` in code runner, to do this, do this:

1. Go to settings
2. Search for code-runner.executorMap
3. Click edit in json
4. look for 'python'
5. change `python -u` to `python3 -u`